# Selecting an element whose parent element does not have a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming, I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="topnav">
    <li class=""><a href="/">Page 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/Page2/">Page 2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/Page3/">Page 3</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/Page4/">Page 4</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="/Page5/">Page 5</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="/Page6/">Page 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the mouse leaves the LI element, it is suppose change the color of the font back to grey except for the A element whose parent LI has a class value of 'active'.

Below is the JQuery code I am trying: (The 'mouseleave' function is not working)

```
        $(".top_nav li a").mouseenter(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#ffffff'}, 'slow');
        });

        $(".top_nav li a").mouseleave(
            function() {
                $(this).parent().not(".active").stop().animate({'color': '#a5acb2'}, 'slow');
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).parent()` selects the `li` element and all other functions apply to this one instead to the `a` element.

You can do:

```
$(this).not(".active > a").stop()...
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/AD9jV/)

Comment: It would also be worth looking into the .hover() function as it will condense your code down.

Comment: That's actually quite clever, but it does require a bit of staring at :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/):

```
if($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#a5acb2'}, 'slow');
}
```

If your list items can only be assigned the one class, you can do this:

```
// class not equals 'active'
$(this).parent("[class!='active']");
```

Otherwise, this should work:

```
// class contains 'active'
$(this).parent("[class*='active']");
```

Comment: The first one won't work, but the second one is good :) *Edit: +1 for the second (and now only) solution.*

Comment: Yeah, I came to realise that :)

Comment: @Felix Kling - two more possibilities thrown in just for fun :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".top_nav li a").hover(  function () {

    $(this).stop().animate({'color': '#ffffff'}, 'slow');

  }, 

  function () {

    $(this).parent().not(".active").stop().animate({'color': '#a5acb2'}, 'slow');

  });
```

Comment: That won't work. Although using `hover` is a better approach, this was not the problem. The problem lies in selecting the right element for the animation.